# How to strengthen my falsetto

Tags: voice, falsetto

i've been practising singing for a few months now and i've quite comfortably found my mixed voice. However i quite enjoy the singing styles of artists such as Blackbear and Eden (vague similarity to Justin Timberlake) in the way they use drop in and out of their falsetto.

Now to me, falsetto is simply singing with your head voice in tune, I'm pretty sure I'm wrong because whenever I try to sing similarly it sounds like a gimmick, and hence very (very) comical. How do I go about making it sound more musical?

The falsetto I'm trying to emulate in question can be found in the following video:

It is present in the beginning and throughout all the hooks.

Comment: Falsetto is not quite the same as high head voice. The vocal cords engage differently. Falsetto usually sounds more breathy or screamy. If you are a classic rock fan: Robert Plant of Led Zeppelin sounds more falsetto, Geddy Lee of Rush sounds more head voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falsetto is as you say, singing in a 'head voice' although both myself and my singing teacher have always agreed the term 'head voice' doesn't really mean anything so to speak it just differentiates chest, belt voice to the other softer, higher head voice.

One thing I will suggest is for you to get a singing teacher. I was always lucky in that I have always been able to do Falsetto *safely.* I say safely, because an untrained singer can do tremendous damage if they are just straining and that can lead to all sorts of complications (if you are on tour or on the stage for example, and you keep going it day after day you can cause a lot of damage).

My singing teacher always told me that more students go to her with bad technique more than bad voices. This is something to remember.

Falsetto should be 'easy'; you should just be able to do it, without your vocal chords screaming for help. Screaming being the operative word there.

When you're finding it difficult, or you can't go from chest to head that is fine, practice sorts everything, but practice safely. Get a singing teacher, tell them it is something you wish to work on and they'll gladly help you. They teach you how to spare your voice, but still sound like you're giving it everything. Of course, it depends how serious you are about it :-)

Comment: mm its not so much that i can do it, I simply can't make it musical without sounding like a cartoon

Comment: It's cartoon like sound is often (and I'm not a singing teacher) through force, lack of technique, but then again it could be just the way you sound. There are loads of professional singers who sound like the Bee Gees in head voice. Keep at it :-)

Comment: @cmp Yeah, I _wish_ my head voice sounded natural like Jared Leto or dramatic like Pavarotti or even edgy like Geddy Lee, but I am far more Brothers Gibb.